# Show that { (x, y) : x > 0 and y > 0 } is path-connected

Tags: multivariable-calculus, connectedness

I am wondering how to go about proving that $$ \{(x, y) \in R^{2} : x > 0, y > 0\} $$. Intuitively, it makes sense that this set, the first quadrant, is path-connected.So I have created a function $$ f : [0, 1] -> Q_{1} $$, specifically $$ f(t) = (y - x)t + x $$, such that f(0) = x and f(1) = y $$ \forall x, y \in Q_{1} $$. I know that this function is continuous on [0, 1], since it is a simple linear equation. How should I show that $$ f(t) \in Q_{1} $$ for all $$ t \in [0, 1] $$?

Comment: OP explicitly writes $x,y\in Q_1$

Comment: I assume the quadrant.

Answer (score 3):

$u=(x,y); v=(x',y'), f(t)=(v-u)t+u=(t(x'-x)+x,t(y'-y)+y), t\in [0,1]$.

$t(x'-x)+x=tx'+(1-t)x>0$ since $t\in [0,1]$ to see this remark that if $t=0, x>0$ done. If $t>0, (1-t)\geq 0, (1-t)x\geq 0$ since $tx'>0, tx'+(1-t)x>0$.